# Audio in to Audio Out

Tags: laptop, audio, speakers

It there any software or any way so that I can change the audio in plugs on my Dell Inspiron 1525 laptops, to an Audio Out, so I can plug my speakers into them.

Comment: The 1525 comes with 1 microphone in and 2 headphone out jacks.  You want 3 total?

Comment: Yes, It's for surround sound

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's a hardware issue.  The circuit is designed for input so software can't touch this, unless there's something weird going on.  If you need two outputs, any reason you can't use a 3.5 splitter?

[image]

Comment: Your image is broken. Do you have the original that you could reupload?

Comment: *If you need two outputs, any reason you can't use a 3.5 splitter?* - He wants surround sound. A splitter would not do that (at least not for real, it would be faked). *No, it's a hardware issue. The circuit is designed for input so software can't touch this, unless there's something weird going on.* - Not necessarily, a lot of audio chips are designed with sensing to allow a single connector to function as either a microphone jack or an output port these days to save space.

Answer (score 0):

You should already have an audio out on that. If you're looking to connect more than a 2 channel speaker system you'll need to get an external sound card.

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia [page for your dell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_Inspiron_1525) shows it has HDMI output.
If your default audio is diverted to that path you might need to do some changes with your mixer settings for getting the audio back to the audio-jack
(I presume you have one, did not see it listed on that wikipedia page;
Meanwhile this [Dell page](http://www.dell.com/content/products/productdetails.aspx/laptop-inspiron-1545) says there is one audio-out jack, does not mention HDMI).

Then you need to identify how your speaker connectors work -- do you have a 3.5mm stereo pin?